# Why the weather layer of google-maps-api-3 stopped reporting on the US?

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I'm developing a custom google map using google-maps-api-3. About a week ago, I started using the weather and cloud overlays provided by google, and it's been working flawlessly until yesterday.

The clouds overlay still works fine, but weather isn't reporting anything in the US or Europe, although most other places on Earth still have their weather info on them.

I know that google weather library will be deprecated in about a year, but until then, it's supposed to keep working as usual right?

PS. Just emphasizing that this is not a problem on my website, but a general problem, as I observe the same behavior on google's developers page: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/layer-weather

Comment: You do realize the [weather layer is deprecated](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/weatherlayer) and will stop working around June 2015 (doesn't explain why it isn't working now though...)

Comment: I know, I was hopping to get away with using it for one or two months for my site, as a proof of concept, and if it works as expected I can switch to a paid API weather service with more flexibility.

Comment: Possibly this [issue](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=6474) come back?